# Trying to rename a file when uploading and it wont work

Tags: php, file, upload, renaming

Hey i am trying to change a file name on upload if it exist but seems i have a problem. here is the code..

```
$tempfilename = $filename["name"]; 
while(file_exists($location . $tempfilename))
{
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; 
    $shuffled = str_shuffle($chars);
    $stringa = substr($shuffled,0,7);
    move_uploaded_file($filename["tmp_name"], $location . $filename["name"]);
    $tempfilename = $stringA.$filename["name"];
}
move_uploaded_file($filename["tmp_name"], $location.$stringa.$filename["name"]);
clearstatcache();
```

This doesn't seem to work and

Don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `clearstatcache()` before `file_exists($location . $tempfilename)`?

Comment: I just tried didnt seem to work.

Comment: Why do i see `move_uploaded_file` in the loop, and outside the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP variable names are case sensitive.

```
$stringA !== $stringa
```

However, rather than all the messing about with shuffling strings etc, have you considered just using a counter?

```
$tempfilename = $filename["name"];
for ($i = 0; file_exists($location . $tempfilename); $i++) {
    $tempfilename = $i . $filename["name"];
}
move_uploaded_file($filename["tmp_name"], $location . $tempfilename);
```

Comment: $stringA !== $stringa happened some how while i wrote the message its not in my code, about using a counter.. would it matter ? i mean the end results are the same - i get different name. it still wouldnt upload it

Comment: if its not uploading, the issue is your PHP settings for the upload, what you are doing here is moving the file and renaming it.

Comment: Uploading it 100% does, i've tried it several time it works .. and now with dave random 's answer it also changes the name however it does save the some of the old name.. like if it was 0file.jpg the next run it becomes 10file.jpg and the next time its 210.jpg :-)

Comment: @YanivKossas I have modified my answer slightly so it will go `file.jpg`, `0file.jpg`, `1file.jpg`, `2file.jpg`, `...` - but are you saying you want to remove the `file` part completely?

Comment: Ah.. i understand why it keep going up and up each run the file adds a number .. it doesnt increase to the number ..

Comment: @DaveRandom, Thanks very much you've being of great assistance. Thanks again